# Bernoulli numbers [A classical introduction to modern number theory]

Tags: number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

I'm struggling with following exercise (Ex.9) from the book in the corresponding chapter.

> Using Lemma 1 show the radius of convergence of $\sum B_nt^n/n!$ is $2\pi$. As a consequence show that for any $C,k>0$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|B_n|>Cn^k$.

Lemma 1 simply says that $$\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_nt^n/n!$$

I managed to show 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{|B_n|}{n!}}=2\pi$$ using identity $2(2m)!\zeta(2m)=(-1)^{m+1}(2\pi)^{2m}B_{2m},$ which does not solves the problem (I mean I'm using stronger fact).

So how can I compute the $\limsup$ using only the Lemma?

I have a problem with the second part as well. From the $\limsup$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $|B_n|/n!<2\pi+\varepsilon$ for every $n>N$. Let us assume $n$ even and fix $\varepsilon.$ Then we have bound $$|B_n|<n!(2\pi+\varepsilon).$$
We know $\forall C,k>0$ there is $M$ such that $Cn^k<n!$ for every $n>M$, so an obvious necessary condition is $n>\max\{N,M\}$. But what else?

Comment: I've just noticed there is a hint in the book "as a function of complex variable $1/(e^t-1)$ is analytic for $|t|<2\pi$", but honestly I don't how it may be helpful, because I'm not very familiar with complex analysis.

Comment: The Taylor series of an analytic function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ about a point $a \in U$ always converges (and represents the function) _at least_ on the largest disk with centre $a$ that is contained in $U$. Take $a = 0$ and $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 2\pi i k : k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \neq 0\}$. (And since $f$ has poles at $\pm 2\pi i$, the radius of convergence is _exactly_ $2\pi$ in this case.)